# Multiple javascript timers on one page with Thymeleaf generated List

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I am struggling with implementing several times on one page.

I made a simple script counting down the time until a certain date, which is different for every div.
It all works fine and dandy on one div, but it does not work on others.

The content where it's displayed is a bootstrap card.
I do not know how many cards will be on the page since they come as a list, so I can't hard code it.

```
<div class="row">
<div th:each=" transport : ${transports}">
    <div class="card ml-1 mr-1 mt-3 mb-3 text-center text-primary">
        <figure>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-text"><small class="text-dark font-italic">Time till departure</small></h6>
                <p  class="timer"><small class="text-muted" id="timer">Time till departure</small></p>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that the problem lies in the id, but how do I dynamically change the id, to it's unique for every card?

I'm using Thymeleaf to generate the template.

I tried to find document.getElementsClassName("timer), but it is nor working.

I'm new to javascript, so I imagine there is best practice to do this, but I did not find the answer.

Thank you for all the tips.

```
<p  class="timer">
<small class="text-muted" id="timer">
Time till departure
</small></p>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        const countDownDate = new Date(/*[[${transport.departureDate}]]*/).getTime();

          const x = setInterval(function () {

          const now = new Date().getTime();

          const distance = countDownDate - now;

          onst days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
          onst hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
          const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
          const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

          if (distance < 0) {
             clearInterval(x);
             document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
             }
               }, 1000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, how are you getting this card and how are you inserting this card inside DOM?

Comment: @lissettdm I updated the code. It's a List <Transport> transportList. The Transport class has departureDate field. It should show an individual timer for every instance of the class

Comment: this `document.getElementsClassName("timer")` returns a Node list, which is pretty similar to an array, so this `document.getElementsClassName("timer")[0]` will grab the first element in that node list

Comment: To create an unique ID, you can use `Date.now()`, this returns a number of miliseconds from Jan 1st 1970 til now

Comment: You can use iterStat to get the index and create a unique id for every card. You say every card has different time, is this Time part of transport object, where do you store the time info?

Comment: @lissettdm could you elaborate? I am totally new to JS.

Comment: @KienHT do you mean document.getElementsByClassName("timer")[0].innerHTML? Because it does not seem to work. Im new to JS, so maybe I am implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using @lissetrdm solution, but all the values had to be in the function.

```
<div th:each=" transport, iterStat : ${transports}">
<p  class="card-text" th:id="'timer-' + ${iterStat.index}"><small class="text-muted" id="timer">Time till departure</small></p>


<script th:inline="javascript">




    var x = setInterval(function () {
        var countDownDate = new Date(/*[[${transport.departureDate}]]*/).getTime();
        var index = [[${iterStat.index}]];

        console.log(index);

        var now = new Date().getTime();

        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        document.getElementById('timer-'+index).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById('timer-'+index).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status). This way you can get the index value and  define an unique class name for every item:

```
    <div th:each=" transport, iterStat : ${transports}">
        <div class="card ml-1 mr-1 mt-3 mb-3 text-center text-primary">
            <figure>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-text"><small class="text-dark font-italic">Time till departure</small></h6>
                    <p  th:id="'timer-' + ${iterStat.index}"><small class="text-muted" id="timer">Time till departure</small></p>
                    <script th:inline="javascript">
                        //...
                        const index=/*[[${iterStat.index}]]*/
                        document.getElementById(`timer-${index}').innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

                         //..
                    </script>
                </div>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer very much, but unfortunately I'm getting an exception
Could not parse as expression: "'timer-'${iterStat.index}" (template: "choose_transport" - line 103, col 25) 

and should this be <p  th:class="'timer-'${iterStat.index}"> or <p  th:id="'timer-'${iterStat.index}"> because document.getElementById referees to an id

Comment: Sorry, Yes should be  (th:id="'timer-' + ${iterStat.index}"). I missed the +. I updated my answer.

Comment: The timer is working only on the last <div>.
Spent so much time on it. Need to move on to another task.
Thank you for your time Sir.